# how to make the user page of my website look less bland

Tags: website-design

I have a websigte that looks super bland, and I'm not sure how to make it look better. anyone have any suggestions?
[image: my website]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  It's pretty hard to answer question this without just expressing personal opinions. What have you tried?  Consider posting some examples for us to choose from. In any case, I'm not sure I would describe it as "bland".  The orange in the side panels is pretty vivid. Perhaps consider toning it down a little. It hurts my eyes.

Comment: Is this your website? No, it's a component of your website. Some consider the look of their "landing page" as representative of their website. This looks pretty clean and easy to use. Maybe redirect your attention to what is the user's "first impression" at the point of arrival. Welcome to GraphicDesign.StackExchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all comes down to form vs. function.

I have **no clue** what the *actual* function of that page may be. It appears to be some sort of database to maintain records or perhaps recordings. So, more informational than entertainment in nature. It does not appear to be a "socially oriented" page. And I have **no clue** what the rest of the site or the overall intention of the site may be. So.... I'm *guessing* based entirely upon that single screenshot of that single page.

## Providing *more information* in the question would help with answers considerably.

Yellows/oranges are generally "loud", "angry", lively" colors. They are often used to make viewers feel either rushed or excited. Few people want to spend a great deal of time in a yellow/orange environment. This is really why nearly all fast food chains use a red/yellow/orange color scheme primarily. They want you to eat and leave, not hang out.

So.. why does this matter....

You *may* feel the page is "bland" because the color choice is kind of "screaming" at the viewer. However, the actual *content* isn't of the "live, active" nature. So there's a direct dichotomy between the initial impression/overall feel and the actual usage of that page at least.

Were you to simply alter the yellow/orange to something more cool, calming, and subtle, on the blue/green side of the spectrum, the visual *may* match the actual usage more closely. And rather than "bland" you may find the page conveys a more "corporate", "professional", "secure" impression.

If you intend to stay with the yellow/orange, then you need to spice things up with more visuals to make the content seem more active, lively, and "fleeting". Whether you do that via photographs or design elements is very, very, difficult to suggest without knowing the actual usage of the page.